# Can I study remotely in a USA university as a foreigner (Covid-19)? What are the prerequisites?

Tags: phd, united-states, university, international-students, online-learning

I thought because of COVID-19 and remote education plans, maybe some universities are providing a remote plan for international students. My goal is a PhD in machine learning, maybe I can start as a remote student and afterwards (after the pandemic) maybe immigrate to USA and complete the studies. The question is are there universities that are providing these kind of remote plans? If yes, what are the conditions?

Comment: Sorry, but this seems to be a "shopping question". I think what you look for would be rare and you would need to ask a few universities specifically about their policies. I doubt that many would consider this to be an ideal plan. Most US doctoral programs start with course work and most universities are wanting to go back to face to face instruction. But you might find something. "Going remote" after passing comprehensive exams might be viable, but less so to start out.

Comment: @Buffy Well, I know that my university in Australia allows for remote learning by international students for its coursework Master's Degree. Not sure about PhDs, though I do know they require a completed Master's Degree for admission into the PhD program.  It seems plausible that at least some universities would allow for the coursework portion of a 5-year PhD to be completed remotely.